# heatsink holder on motherboard cracked

Tags: dell-poweredge, hardware, oem

I have an old Dell Poweredge 830 server. I just moved about 250 miles, and in that process broke something in the server.

After some issues with the CPU fan not slowing down I realized that one of the two plastic hooks that holds a bar in place that keeps the heatsink in contact with the CPU broke. If I had a replacement this would seem to be a very easy thing to fix.

I believe the CPU was a Pentium D 3Ghz. From what I can find through googling this would suggest an LGA-775 socket, but this plastic holder looks different from anything I have ever seen on an LGA-775 (which I am somewhat familiar with).

Does anyone know if this heatsink holder is a custom Dell part or part of a socket type I have not seen before? Is this something I can get a replacement for the broken part or will I need to remove it all together and purchase a new heatsink with a different mounting system?

The server is 7 years old now, so way out of warranty. It was still serving in many capacities very well and I would love to get it running again but I can't afford to replace the mobo. Thanks

Comment: downvote? Is this not the proper place for a question like this or does someone just not like my question?

Comment: I'd guess it was downvoted because the knowledge required to answer your question is highly vendor specific. Dell will probably be the best people to talk to. Also: Why are you using a seven year old server without any warranty plan in production?

Comment: @KCE - Thanks, I use it at home for various purposes, it's a former business server. The RAID array is nice for family photo, video, and email storage. I was also running a back up SVN repository off of it. The hardware still is capable but maintaining a maintenance contract doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You might look to see if you can purchase a replacement from dell or maybe even order from the local dell service repair shop.  It's possible that this is a standard part but given the constraints of rack mount server hardware it's likely that's is a custom molding.

Comment: Bests to call Dell for the part.  Worst case you can get a used mother board on eBay.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering a replacement from Dell may cost too much for a 7 year old server. I would recommend just removing all of Dell's ducting parts and putting a decent LGA775 socket cooler inside. Newegg.com is a great place to look. It will most likely lower your temps anyway taking this route.

Comment: Thanks, the only reason I didn't do this right away is it just didn't look like an LGA-775, but maybe once everything is taken off it will. Figured a post here might uncover someone who knew about the exact Dell setup.